# Aqueduct server quits working after upgrading to 4.0.0

Tags: dart, aqueduct

I upgraded Dart to 2.8.4 and Aqueduct to 4.0.0-b1.

On the linux server I was starting the server with a daemon like this:

```sh
[Unit]
Description=My server

[Service]
User=web
WorkingDirectory=/home/web/dart/my_server
ExecStart=/home/web/.pub-cache/bin/aqueduct serve
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But Aqueduct won't start now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pub run` to start Aqueduct now:

```sh
pub run aqueduct serve
```

In version 4.0.0 the Aqueduct server is AOT compiled. (I'm not sure yet why that means you have to use `pub run`, though.)

Your daemon file should be changed to this (depending on the location of pub on your system):

```sh
ExecStart=/usr/lib/dart/bin/pub run aqueduct serve
```